# Joining points in multiple polygon features? Union with points and polygons?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins, analysis, union

I have a shapefile full of points (points.shp) and another shapefile with polygons (polygons.shp). Polygons.shp has multiple features in it, many of them overlapping with each other.

I would like the run an analysis [like a union] where every combination of points.shp and polygon.shp is returned.

Currently I am separating the features in polygons.shp into different files where there are no overlaps, since QGIS's Join Attributes By Location tool will only return a 1:1 match.

Is there a faster or better way to be doing this in QGIS?

Comment: You want to get a union of all the points in a particular polygon?

Comment: Please make sure that you post GIS questions on [gis.se] rather than [meta.gis.se] (which is for questions about how GIS SE works).  Also, I removed ArcMap from your question to leave it focussed on QGIS.  As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question, and by asking about two products it would effectively be two questions.

Comment: a Join Attributes by Location analysis will return the attributes of one polygon to a point. I would like to return one point and polygon information for every polygon that the point intersects, similar to a polygon with polygon union.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a single tool or plugin that can perform the steps you've outlined, i.e. union, split features etc...

To speeds things up on step of separating the features in the polygon.shp file you can use the `Split Vector Layer` tool.

Look in Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector Layer...

[image]

Comment: hi whyzar, I have already been doing this to avoid the overlapping layers, then Join Attributes by Location tool for the points over each set of features then putting all the information back together. I am wondering if there is a more systematic or faster way than this. The polygon.shp file has more than 2000 features, maybe 1500 of them overlapping each other.